# ExtJS 4 - не возвращает актуальные value

Tags: extjs

Доброго времени суток. Есть следующее (пример урезан):

```
    Ext.define('sdfAdmin.controller.LoginController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'loginField',
            selector: '#mytextfield6'
        },
        {
            ref: 'pwdField',
            selector: '#mytextfield7'
        },
        {
            ref: 'mybutton3',
            selector: '#mybutton3'
        },
        {
            ref: 'loginErrorMessage',
            selector: '#myfieldcontainer7'
        },
        {
            ref: 'loginForm',
            selector: '#myform8'
        }
    ],

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var login = this.getLoginForm();

        console.log(login.getValues()); // Вот тут
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "#mybutton3": {
                click: this.onButtonClick
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Обратите вниманиие на то, что при событии нажатия на кнопку я выдираю все values из формы.
Приходит следующее (в консоль):
    Object {login: "", password: ""}

Хотя значения в формах были изменены. не пойму в какую сторону копать.
P.S. Если я даже не буду брать значения из формы, а напрямую буду доставать значения из каждого филда - оно всегда будет пустым.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была с неправильным видением архитектуры фрэймворка.
Решено правильной линковкой контроллера и view части.